# Mr Green in the Study with the Knife - Who broke the build?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit

How do you determine responsibility for build test failures?   We have a large maven java build of about 80 modules with 25000 tests.  When our nightly completes we have a list of existing and new failures.

When a test fails we have the following data:

- committers since last build
- call stack from unit test failure
- source code
- maven dependency tree

We can base assignment on the following:

- all who committed since last test
- who last touched the test source file
- who last touched the test (find test in call stack, find line, use SVN blame to determine author)

What I'd like to do is to determine why the test broke, find the best investigator and have them fix it.  However, the unit test performs an action, checks and assertion and then throws.  The call stack is from the assertion not from where the problem happened.

I guess I could scan the file and track down the object in use prior to assertion.

- Find that object's source file.  I would only look at my objects not 3rdparty
- Determine if it was modified since last passing test.
- Use blame to identify author

Does anyone have a better idea or know of a plugin that handles some or all of this analysis?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 3):

If your tests were better named and output better messages when they failed, *in theory* you shouldn't need a stack trace directly to the cause of the problem.  It'd enlighten the person as to why/how they broke the code when they made my commit.  I don't know if that's an option in reality though, especially because worse case, you may have to modify 25,000 tests.

It sounds like the tools you're asking for are already the tools you're using.  You have automated tests and a list of who committed when the build broke.  I think the biggest problem is your feedback loop takes a whole night.  If you had more unit tests that ran frequently, it'd be more obvious when you broke the build because you'd be informed of it faster.

Comment: Right,  I could break the build up into individual module builds that ran in CI and exercised tests throughout the day.  I'm using maven, so that configuration wouldn't been all that difficult.